# JAXP validation returns non-mandatory fields

Tags: java, xml-validation, xerces, javax.xml

I have a project whose main goal is to validate xml against xsd.
I use Java 1.8 from Adoptium and I initiate the SchemaFactory this way:

`SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI, "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory", null)`

When I have the following xsd:

```
    <xs:complexType name="PersonType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="NickName"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Address"/>
            <xs:element name="Surname"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Occupation"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

Using the following xml:

```
<Person/>
```

returns the following error:
`cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'Person' is not complete. One of '{"namespace":NickName, "namespace":Address, "namespace":Surname}' is expected.`

This error is misleading since the user should only provide the mandatory element `Surname` but it's not clear from the error he/she gets.

So, how can I make the validation to return only the mandatory fields in the error description?

I tried to modify the source code of the library but this is impossible since this is Java embedded and also the code which decides these fields has a strange logic.